# Using custom glibc with bazel

Tags: c, linker, glibc, bazel, thread-local-storage

I am in a non-root (debian) environment and when compiling a binary I got a

```
Failed to open library! - ./libdmlab.so
dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

I learned that this is a somewhat common problem and was circumvented in  [glibc/2.21.1](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=793689) by increasing the limit. I am now trying to locally install a newer (2.22) version of glibc and link using it in bazel.

I have compiled glibc from the sources and added appropriate things to `PATH`, `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`. Adding `glibc/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` made `ldd` segfault, so I removed it.

Now comes the question of using the locally installed glibc in bazel. I have tried using `-linkeropt` (as well as `-copt`) as:

```
bazel run --linkopt "-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" run //target
```

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/1951176), but it didn't change anything. I also tried adding

```
"-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc",
"-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
```

to the `linkeropts` of the problematic library in the `BUILD` file, but it didn't help either.

How can I make `bazel` link against my version of `glibc` for all of the targets? Can I in any other way circumvent the problem of hitting static TLS limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bazel run --linkopt "-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" run //target`

This doesn't look right: you have two `run`s in there. Also, passing a single `-Wl,--rpath...ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` argument to the linker is not going to do what you want. You need either:

```
--linkopt=-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc \
--linkopt=-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

or:

```
 --linkopt=-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc,--dynamic-linker=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Finally, your `--rpath` value: `/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc` looks wrong. It should likely be:

```
-Wl,--rpath=/u/sygnowsj/bin/glibc/lib
```

(since that's where your `ld-linux` resides).

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that I was linking correctly with glibc, but the error laid elsewhere.